Number of continuous functions $f:X\to X$ over finite topological space $X$
Given a finite set $X$ and some topology $\mathcal{O}$ on $X$ is there a formula for the number of continuous functions from $(X,\mathcal{O})$ into itself?
If the topology is trivial, i.e., contains only $X$ and the empty set, then every function is continuous and same when the topology contains all subsets. But what happens in between?
This becomes even more unclear if the maps are not between the same topological space because then the case discussed above evolves to the trivial topology on the target space and the power set on the base space.
Has anyone a source on this? Or an idea where to start? The problem becomes rapidly unweildy due to the large number of finite topologies.

No, this is a hard problem.

So noone has ever done any work on this? I did not find anything during an mathscinet search neither during a Google scholar search

Well since homeomorphism are a subgroup of permutations of $X$, the number of homeomorphism has to divide $|X|!$ (I know this isn't very helpful, I just wanted to say this).

If the topology is discrete, then just as for the trivial topology, every function is continuous. Also, topologies on finite sets are equivalent to preorders, so the problem is equivalent to finding the number of order-preserving functions $(X, \le) \to (X, \le)$ for a given preorder $\le$ on $X$.
